# How to configure Roambi Upload Utility?

Tags: upload, uri, utility

Im trying to configure Roambi Upload Utility for Windows. I created the API client through the admin panel, but when i try to set up the API i get the error "**Configuration validate failed**" and i have no idea why.

Im using this [post](https://support.roambi.com/entries/22077350-API-Utility-Roambi-Upload-Utility-for-Windows) at Roambi-Support as a reference (there´s almost nooo documentation).

The fields that goes on the utilty are 
 User - Password 
 Client ID (Provided by the Admin Panel) 
 Client secret (Provided by the Admin Panel) 
 Redirect URI (i put https://roambi.com) 
 Local Sync Folder (the local folder to sync)

If anyone has use the API before i appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this as well:

- Delete the API client from Roambi Business and create a new one.
- Reinstall the Windows Upload Utility and ensure the consumer key and secret are copied exactly from the new API Client.
- For the Redirect URI use the following:  about:blank
- Create a new sync folder and try adding the Excel file again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a registered Roambi user, please go here for more information and instruction on how to use the Roambi Upload Utility:

https://support.roambi.com/entries/22077350-API-Utility-Roambi-Upload-Utility-for-Windows

Please make sure you are logged in as an admin when installing the utility in Windows..